# Get value from db and show it in list view and set click listener on it

Tags: android

I am new to android development and i am doing my Final year project. In my project i want to perform search action . search from database and show it in list view so multiple results could be there . so i want to set click listener on it.but every thing is working but when i tried to click on list view results. Its no working .. please give me some suggestions or any guideline. I have already searched all the posts here related to my problem but its not solved . please
here is my java code and in method SeeProfile OnClick event is set

```
public class DisplaySearchResults extends ActionBarActivity {
String json_string, json_string2;
JSONObject jsonObject, JsonObject2;
JSONArray jsonArray, jsonArray2;
AdapterSearchElements adapterSearchElements;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search_results);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewsearch);

    listView.setAdapter(adapterSearchElements);

    adapterSearchElements = new AdapterSearchElements(this, R.layout.searchresultcutomrow);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterSearchElements);
    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;
        String name, Gender, address;
        while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name = JO.getString("name");
            Gender = JO.getString("Gender");
            address = JO.getString("address");
            SearchResultsElements searchResultsElements = new SearchResultsElements(name, Gender, address);
            adapterSearchElements.add(searchResultsElements);

            count++;


        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void SeeProfile(View view){
    json_string2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
    Intent i = new Intent(DisplaySearchResults.this, FriendsProfile.class);
    i.putExtra("json_data", json_string2);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set listview OnItemClickListener. Examples are below:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 0):

i think you are wrong way to fill up listview.and do googling how to bind adapter.

follow on this way ..

```
json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;
        String name, Gender, address;
        while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name = JO.getString("name");
            Gender = JO.getString("Gender");
            address = JO.getString("address");
            SearchResultsElements searchResultsElements = new SearchResultsElements(name, Gender, address);
            adapterSearchElements.add(searchResultsElements);
            count++;
        }
        adapterSearchElements = new AdapterSearchElements(this, R.layout.searchresultcutomrow);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterSearchElements);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

first add array value in Arraylist then after bind adapter.

Comment: this thing is working ... data is perfectly working but clicklistener is not working

Comment: clicklistener  is working but i want to pass selected data and pass it to another activity